# Using text from previous commands' output

Tags: bash, command-line, osx, io-redirection

EDIT April, 2015: 
If you have this same question I recommend also checking http://xiki.org/

---

I know this is not how terminals work, but I find myself often wishing there was an easy way of using text (copying it, modifying it, etc) that is already on my terminal window history from some previous command output.

I've imagined it like this:

I'm at my bash shell about to enter a command and I realize I need to type something that is already on the screen a few lines above. I can reach for the mouse and select it, but I hate that. What I really wish at this moment is that my whole terminal became a giant Vim buffer, all of it: the prompts, the commands I've typed, and the output from those commands. Everything. And then I could jump a few lines up, maybe edit a little, and yank some text. Then, return to bash shell mode and paste whatever I yanked into the current command line.

I know there are some options:

- Naturally, pipe the text I need directly from some command's output to a file, or right to the next command. But for that you have to plan in advance or re-execute the command from your history (supposing the output won't change between invocations).
- To reach for the mouse and select the text to copy. Lame, annoying, I wish I hadn't to do that, (this isn't the GUI stackexchange site, is it? =)
- To use my (Mac OS X) Terminal application's "Export text as..." option, and save the terminal text to a file. Then open the file and work with it. Almost, but why go through the step of saving to a file on disk?

So the question is: What do you do in this situation? Is there any trick, tool, shell feature that could be useful in this scenario? Do you just resign yourself to use the mouse or re-type whatever you need to type?

It might be that the problem is that I'm not doing things 'the unix way', but c'mon, this is 2010 and I cannot easily copy some text a few lines away from my cursor?

Comment: See also [How do I reuse the last output from the command line?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9024).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955577/bash-automatically-capture-output-of-last-executed-command-into-a-variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use script (use -f to make sure it flushes every time) and you can have all the output in a file.

Use a terminal multiplexer (screen, tmux etc). For instance, for screen
http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/screen_11.html#

> Command: copy Enter copy/scrollback
>   mode. This allows you to copy text
>   from the current window and its
>   history into the paste buffer. In this
>   mode a vi-like full screen editor is
>   active, with controls as outlined
>   below.

Other terminal multiplexers surely have more advanced capabilities.

Comment: Ok. I just learned that a 'Terminal Multiplexer' is probably what I need. Thanks. Also, thanks for the 'script' command hint.

Answer (score 5):

In emacs, [M-x shell](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Interactive-Shell.html#Interactive-Shell) handle edition of previous output. You can easily copy paste previous commands output, or any part of your buffer, like a regular buffer. I am pretty sure there should be a vim equivalent.

Comment: That is very near to what I want, but I need to be in Emacs or Vim already. +1

Comment: Yes, it could be your default term+shell. :) Then you'd use the usual text navigating keys there as a minimum. If you learned more special keys, then [the following features of Emacs' `eshell` can be accessed](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385/using-text-from-previous-commands-output/9776#9776).

Answer (score 5):

In tmux (a terminal multiplexer) you can press Ctrl+A-[ to switch to the Vi buffer mode where you can navigate around the screen, scroll the buffer back and forth, copy text etc. The default shortcut is actually Ctrl+B-[ but that was obviously meant to be reconfigured. Also, the default buffer mode is Emacs but you can configure it to be Vi.

Check out tmux, it really is a great modern terminal multiplexer. Besides working with buffer you can split screen in multiple windows, connect to the same session from multiple terminals etc. For ultimate convenience you can even make it your login shell if you tell it what your actual shell is.

On OpenBSD tmux was even made part of the base system.

See man page for tmux for more details. Also see screenshots on http://tmux.sourceforge.net/

Comment: tmux is the coolest!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned here, the Emacs' `eshell` could be your default term+shell. :) Then you'd use the usual text navigating keys there as a minimum. If you learned more special keys, then the following features of Emacs' `eshell` can be accessed:

- [navigating, i.e. jumping, between the past cmd prompts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3650/would-it-be-possible-to-jump-between-prev-next-command-prompts/3729#3729),
- [marking and narrowing to the output of previous cmds](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3650/would-it-be-possible-to-jump-between-prev-next-command-prompts/9745#9745),
- [substituting the output of the last cmd for a special shell var in the cmd prompt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9024/how-do-i-reuse-the-last-output-from-the-command-line/9399#9399).

Answer (score 1):

I use urxvt (rxvt-unicode) and there is a package called urxvt-keyboard-select
which may be exactly what you want, if you can install urxvt. The Archlinux package information (that contains pointers) is here:

https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=39950

Original source:
http://www.github.com/muennich/urxvt-perls

Answer (score 1):

Try using vim as your CLI?  Just select the output from a few lines up and pipe it through :!.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow you. Can you elaborate, please?