# bash: get last stdout

Tags: bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I reuse the last output from the command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9024/how-do-i-reuse-the-last-output-from-the-command-line)

If I for example type

```
aptitude search dia
```

I get a lot of unrelated stuff. At that point, I suspect that `| head` or `| grep -w dia` would have streamlined the result (had I thought of that). I could type `!! | head` or `!! | grep -w dia` but then the search is performed anew. But that's unnecessary; I'm already happy with that part. So, is there anyway to do like, `most_recent_stdout | whatever`.

(Note that this is just an example so I'm not looking for aptitude options or anything like that.)

Answer (score 8):

To make this work, you would need to redirect `stdout` to a file and then cat that file. Bash doesn't save the output of commands on its own.

Alternatively, you could use a program like `screen` that allows you to save a transcript of your session to a file. You would get the output of everything and the command lines though.

Comment: If redirecting to a file could somehow be automatic, a small tool to access those files wouldn't be that difficult to write. But If you had to write `> stdoutlog` after each command, it wouldn't be worth the effort because you would never use it anyway.

Comment: You could certainly implement this by hacking bash, but I would strongly advise against it. For a start, it would litter your filesystem with these files, potentially overwriting other files. Furthermore, you would have trouble redirecting output to another file.